# Unabl to read EXIF when uploading to s3

Tags: media

I am uploading files to s3 bucket. Using `exif_orientation` to read exif data.
It works fine for local image. But when we are uploading to Amazon s3, it is unable to read EXIF data.
Reason I found is `drupal_realpath` function, that cant read from remote servers.
What should be the alternative to this?
How can we read EXIF data of a remote image then?

The other thin I am trying is reading EXIF from tmp image..

```
$source = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name']['field_image_und_9'];
$file_exif = exif_read_data($source);
```

But that shows this warning...

```
Warning: exif_read_data(): Unable to open file in _exif_orientation_rotate() (line 53 of /var/www/sitename.com/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/exif_orientation/exif_orientation.module).
```

Comment: Related: [Remote File Support for S3 Bucket](https://www.drupal.org/node/2325141)

Comment: I have gone through it. Its not working for me.